# How do I go about turning on MySQL error messages.

Tags: mysql

I'm currently running 3 Solaris servers running MySQL 4.0.20 and PHPMyAdmin 2.11.5 and on one server, when I run a MySQL query through PHPMyAdmin with an error in it, I get a helpful error message along the lines of

```
MySQL said: 
#1054 - Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'
```

Whereas on the main web server I get this from the same query on the same table.

```
MySQL said: 
#1054 -
```

I get the error code but no message telling me where the error is which makes debugging queries a lot more time consuming.

I've compared the mysql init files and mysql daemon and can't see where the error reporting is configured. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not mention operating system you are using, my answer assumes it's linux / debian. but those hints might be handy with windows as well.

compare both servers - check if mysql has the same language setting. run in mysql:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%lang%';
+---------------+---------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                     |
+---------------+---------------------------+
| language      | /usr/share/mysql/english/ |
+---------------+---------------------------+
```

it can be changed in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
language        = /usr/share/mysql/english
```

is it the same on both machines? on debian mysql's textual explanation of errors is kept in /usr/share/mysql.

check regional settings if both machines have the same default language.
you can check/change default locales by running
`enter code here`dpkg-reconfigure locales

Comment: we're using solaris. i'll check these files now and compare. cheers!

Comment: both are using english. is there an option in my.cnf to tun on error messages?

Comment: @ewengcameron - i'm not aware of such my.cnf option. but take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-message-language.html . that's more or less what i've written already but check it anyway.

Comment: cheers! That looks like the right stuff! Will update this in a few minutes when I confirm if it works!